# don't retrieve object on php page which passed from ajax call

Tags: php, json, ajax

Hi i don't get retrieve Ajax Data to PhP page its throwing error. i pass data as json object.
The error i'm getting is

[image]

Edit.php

```
$('#regForm').on('submit', function (e) {
var url = document.URL;                // Get current url

var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);

var data1 = $("#regForm").serialize();

data = {data:data1,id:id};

console.log(data)
$.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url: 'update.php',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function () {
      alert('form was submitted');
    }
  });

});
```

update.php

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))  
{  

  print_r($_POST['data']);

  // Error::: Undefined index:data in
```

Comment: The error tell you what is wrong and where, so what is your question?

Comment: pass object data = {data:data1,id:id}; to update.php page and want to id and form data with this object

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: You need to `e.preventDefault()` at the bottom of your `.on('submit', function(e){ /* your code here */; e.preventDefault(); }`. `isset($_POST['submit'])` should be false because you're using AJAX. Just test for `isset($_POST['data'])`. `dataType` in jQuery .ajax is for returned data to the success function as argument. Use `echo json_encode($assocArrayorObject);` in PHP to return to arg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass Id using hidden input field and then form data serialize then after you can use by name wise on php page.
$_POST['name'];

Answer (score 0):

Read my comment, then look at this:

***JavaScript may look like this***

```
$('#regForm').on('submit', function(e){
  var s = location.search.split('&'), serialId = s[s.length-1], idArray = serialId.split('=');
  if(idArray.length === 2 && idArray[1].trim() !== '' && idArray[0].match(/^id$/i)){
    var serialData = $(this).serialize()+'&'+serialId;
    $.ajax({
      method:'POST', url:'update.php', dataType:'json', data:serialData},
      success:function(jsonObj){
        console.log(jsonObj);
      }
    });
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

***PHP may look like this***

```
<?php
if($_POST['id']){
  // each property as $_POST[propertyHere]
  // sending back to JavaScript
  $c = new stdClass; $c->someProp = 'some value';
  echo json_encode($c); // dataType is json so you should get Object as result
}
?>
```

Comment: You still aren't preventing the default form submit event action. Also, `serialData` is not JSON so trying to decode it as such will not work

Comment: What's the reason to put e.preventDefault(); at the bottom instead of the top?

Comment: @StackSlave that's not true at all

Comment: I just got used to putting it on the bottom, just in case some Browser has a strange behavior of stopping anything from occurring after that.